# Tengo un problema al tratar de usar un JSON para obtener las imágenes de unas películas en React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando un proyecto de películas así que estoy usando un JSON para pasar el título, el año, el genero, y la ubicación del poster de la película, dentro de un componente Row estoy requiriendo la información de la siguiente forma.

```
import React from "react";


const Row = ({ title, isLargeRow, movies }) => {
  const baseUrl = "./assets/moviescarat/";
  return (
    <div className=" text-white ml-[20px] flex flex-col ">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold capitalize">
        {title}
      </h2>
      
      <div className="movie_poster__scrollbar gap-3 flex overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll p-[20px]">
        {movies.map(unitary_movie =>
          <React.Fragment>
            <h1>
              {unitary_movie.title}
            </h1>
            <img
              key={unitary_movie.id}
              onClick={() => alert("funciona click")}
              className={`movie_poster`}
              src= {require(`${baseUrl}${unitary_movie.poster}`).default}
              alt={unitary_movie.name}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Row;
```

luego este recibe los parametros en el app.js

```
import Banner from "./components/Banner";
import Row from "./components/Row";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import moviesJson from "./assets/movies/movies.json";
const movieconst = Object.values(moviesJson.movies);
console.log(movieconst);
function App() {
 

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#111] w-screen overflow-x-hidden">
      <Navbar />
      <Banner />
      <Row title="Movies" isLargeRow movies={movieconst}/>{" "}
       {/* <Row title="Animations" fetchUrl={requests.fetchAnimations} />{" "}  */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

el problema es que al tratar de requerir cada imagen no las detecta salta el siguiente error

```
^.*.*$:17 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './assets/moviescarat/the_godfather.jpg'
    at webpackContextResolve (^.*.*$:17:1)
    at webpackContext (^.*.*$:12:1)
    at Row.jsx:22:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Row (Row.jsx:12:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
```

pero al usar la ruta en forma de texto si funciona, siendo que requiero iterar cada una de forma independiente uso dos variables para crear cada ruta y requerirlas.

Ayuda!

Comment: ¿Que tipo regresa esto `'./assets/moviescarat/the_godfather.jpg'`?